# Get status of slot swap on Azure websites?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm building a Web App named `fooapp` on Azure's App Service platform and is configured to have slot named `slot1`

Currently I'm programatically swapping my slot named `slot1` into my actual web app named `fooapp` via [Azure's ARM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/azure/dn790568.aspx) consumed by a HTTP client written in C# . The possible endpoints can be explored using the [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/).

This works but swap itself takes around 1-2 minutes so I would like to notify myself via email when the swap is complete. Is there an endpoint to call for the status for the swap?

Here is the code that's making the HTTP Json Post to swap `slot1` with `fooapp` in C#.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fooapp/slots/slot1/slotsswap?api-version=2015-08-01";
var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, new { targetSlot = "production" });
```

Ideas anyone? I've tried scouting for documentation but with the ever expanding features provided by Azure it's desert dry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Activity Log API to keep track of the status of your slots swapping. Here is a simple sample call of the REST API.

```
HTTP Method:
GET

Absolute Uri:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2016-09-08T01:53:03.0422573Z' and eventTimestamp le '2016-09-08T02:53:03.0422573Z' and resourceUri eq '/subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/resourcegroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fooapp/slots/slot1'&select=Authorization,Caller,CorrelationId,Category,EventTimestamp,OperationName,ResourceGroupName,ResourceUri,Status,SubscriptionId,SubStatus
```

For this REST API, there are a few things you need to be careful with.

1. Be aware that you might need URL encoding.
2. You need to change `eventTimestamp ge '2016-09-08T01:53:03.0422573Z'`, setting "eventTimestamp" to be greater than or equal to a timestamp that just before you call the slots swapping.
3. Similar for `eventTimestamp le '2016-09-08T02:53:03.0422573Z'`. You should set "eventTimestamp" to be less than or equal to the current timestamp.

There are 3 possible logs you are going to get, that indicating you slots swapping succeeds.

First one, "Started".

```
Authorization     :
                    Scope     : /subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/resourcegroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fooapp/slots/slot1
                    Action    : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/slotsswap/action
                    Role      :
                    Condition :
Caller            : <your Azure account>
CorrelationId     : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Category          : Administrative
EventTimestamp    : 2016-09-08 2:48:39 AM
OperationName     : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/slotsswap/action
ResourceGroupName : {myresourcegroup}
ResourceId        :
Status            : Started
SubscriptionId    : {mysubscriptionid}
SubStatus         :
```

Second one, "Accepted".

```
Authorization     :
                    Scope     : /subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/resourcegroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fooapp/slots/slot1
                    Action    : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/slotsswap/action
                    Role      :
                    Condition :
Caller            : <your Azure account>
CorrelationId     : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Category          : Administrative
EventTimestamp    : 2016-09-08 2:48:41 AM
OperationName     : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/slotsswap/action
ResourceGroupName : {myresourcegroup}
ResourceId        :
Status            : Accepted
SubscriptionId    : {mysubscriptionid}
SubStatus         : Accepted
```

Third one, "Succeeded".

```
Authorization     :
                    Scope     : /subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/resourcegroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fooapp/slots/slot1
                    Action    : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/write
                    Role      :
                    Condition :
Caller            : <your Azure account>
CorrelationId     : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Category          : Administrative
EventTimestamp    : 2016-09-08 2:49:44 AM
OperationName     : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/write
ResourceGroupName : {myresourcegroup}
ResourceId        :
Status            : Succeeded
SubscriptionId    : {mysubscriptionid}
SubStatus         :
```

If you are using Service Principal, the "caller" in the outputs may be different. If the slots swapping failed, you will get a "Failed" for the second or the third log.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response! I have it working now but I would like to ask where you got this information from? I was not able to find this on Azure's website. Also I wasn't able to find `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/providers/microsoft.insights` on the Azure Resource Explorer but when i put iin my REST client e.g. Postman the Absolute uri worked

Comment: I got this information by investigating the Azure PowerShell Command `Get-AzureRmLog`. If you run the command with option `-debug`, you will be able to see the REST API. For Example, `Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceId /subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/resourcegroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fooapp/slots/slot1 -debug`.